# Is there a way to get wp_editor (tinymce) content?

Tags: php, tinymce, wp-editor, regex

I want to get the wp_editor (tinymce) content then find a sentence by specific word with regex. However, have no idea how to get the content

When a post is published or updated, the function will get the content and then find a sentence by the specific word.

My regex to get a whole sentence:

```
$regex = '/<p>Chapter(.*?)<\/p>/'; //Specific Word = Chapter
$chapnumber = '';
$chaptitle = '';
$chapcontent = "<p>Chapter 136 – Tibet and West Turk</p>"; //This should be the content
if (preg_match($regex, $chapcontent, $matches)) {
    echo $matches[1];
}
```

Any solution about this?

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment yet... so I will use an answer, I think you need to do it with 'wp_insert_post_data' filter.

You can see this in line 3523 here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/

Your function need to have a parameter, which is an array. From there you should get the content from 'post_content' key.

```
add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data', 'example' );
function example( $data ){
    $post_content = $data['post_content'];
    // ... do your stuff
    $data['post_content'] = $post_content;
    return $data
}
```

Note: this will not get the tinymce content, This will get the data right before it's introduced in database. You should also take some attention at shortcodes, I don't think that you can modify the content in shortcodes via that filter.
Hope it helps you, or someone else.

Comment: It seems still can't get the content, I try it with update_post_meta as a test and resulting nothing to set/save content to value of a custom field. (The content test has one sentence only)

Answer (score 0):

You could hook a filtering function to [`save_post`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post) action and then get the post content either from the `$_POST` variable or by using `get_post($post_id)` for filtering.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by myself, instead of doing an ajax. This more simpler to me:

```
$post_content = wpautop( $post->post_content );
```